# Handle timeout of HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android

I want to do something after timeout. but my code is not doing anything and it's just keep trying to connect...

```java
try {
    URL url = new URL(p1[0]);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    con.setReadTimeout(5000);
    if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( in ));
        res = br.readLine();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    Global.mkOkDialog(c, "Couldn't connect to server.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the message above in catch block not showing at all after 5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don' actually connect to anything, you should call `con.connect()`. Catch block gets executed only in case of `IOException` which is not happening.

Comment: As I can see it, the explicit ```con.connect()``` is not needed.
```HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());``` prints ```200``` for me.

Comment: i called it, nothing happened. keep just trying to connect.. but wait.. is the timeoutrequest works just if the server is busy or slow or it works even if the device has no internet data but internet is on and trying to connect??

Comment: @MaxRumford true, `con.connect()` doesn't need to be called explicitly as `con.getResponseCode()` calls `getInputStream()` which opens connection.

Answer (score 0):

With `if(con.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)` you're checking if the HTTP-Response-Code is 200, which it is if you get an ok-response. Any other response code is not handled by your program and thus does not execute any further code.

Comment: i removed that if steatment but nothing changed

Comment: For starters, you could try to find out what ```con.getResponseCode()``` actually returns and work with that. Just because no ```IOException``` is thrown doesn't mean the Connection itself was not successful.